# SharePoint REST - Change Author on file

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, author

Having a difficult time changing the author of a sharepoint item such as a file.
The actual jsonstring i am using:

```
{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentsItem' } ,'AuthorId': '20'}
```

Posted to this url:

```
https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(137)
```

I have set Created By to Readonly=false which works fine, but the Created By or Modified By is not changing and i am not getting errors. 
Do i need something else in my request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For `update` operation, the following actions are required:

- Create an `HTTP` request using the `POST` verb.
- Add an `X-HTTP-Method` header with a value of `MERGE`.
- Use the service URL of the list item you want to update as the target
  for the `POST`
- Add an `If-Match` header with a value of the entity’s original ETag.

The following example demonstrates how to update *single-valued* user field:

```
var listTitle = 'Requests';
var listItemId = 1;
var properties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.RequestsListItem" },
    'AssignedToId': 1  //single-valued User field value 
};
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")";
updateJson(requestUrl,properties)
.done(function(data){
   console.log('List item has been updated'); 
})
.fail(function(error){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
})
```

where

```
function updateJson(url,payload)
{
   return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
         "If-Match": "*"
      }
   });    
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.
The problem is not the update itself, i can update a number of metadata just fine, but the Author (Created By/Modified By) seems untouchable. Any input on this?

Comment: @Tobias Callenryd, in your example there is a typo, `UserId` have to be specified as a numeric value, so `'AuthorId': '20'` need to be replaced with `'AuthorId': 20`

Comment: I tried this approach but it's still not changing anything. I don't get errors either. Is AuthorId the correct name?

Comment: `AuthorId` corresponds to `Modified By` system field, so once `ReadOnly` property is set to false, it could be modified.

Comment: So the ReadOnly = false should target AuthorId, not Modified By ?

Comment: My mistake `AuthorId` corresponds to `Created By` system field

Comment: Regarding your last comment, `AuthorId` is name of field that is getting generated by SharePoint REST service, so the answer is no, you **cant** set to read only `AuthorId` since such field physically does not exist, but you could set its property for `Created By` field (internal name: `Author`)

Comment: Thanks, yes i got that to work. Both Modified By and Created By are set to Readonly=false. Still, the actual call to set them to another user remains unsolved for some reason. Tried every possible combination. Got a working example that you wanna share?